# Get multiple values from column Q, add a "." and search in column A if exist, then delete

Tags: excel, vba

I'm unable to find a solution for this question:

I've a sheet with Billing of materials. The sheet is like this:

https://ibb.co/xsJ7mfg

In column B there is a code start with "SGA" or "SLA" that i need to delete all sub code. In this case in a row B27 there is a code "SLA30521208" (position in column A 1.19.3) and i want to delete the sub code "SLE30521208" and "SLE30521206".

In my macro i've get the corrispective number of the "SGA" and "SLA" and copied in column Q.

Now i want to get the values of each cell from column Q, add a "." and compare with column A. If match result, clear cell of corrispective row in column B.
Can someone help?

This is for excel

```
Sub CopiaSgaSla()
    ary = Array("SGA", "SLA")
    Dim v As String, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim valore As String
    Dim Vdec As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim r As Excel.Range
    Dim d As Excel.Range
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        v = ary(i)
        For j = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
            If InStr(1, Cells(j, "B"), v) > 0 Then
                valore = Cells(j, "A").Value



                Cells(j, "Q").Value = valore
            End If

        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have to add a dot?

Comment: Because for me is simplest way to delete the sub code. But if there is another solution, i'm listening

Comment: I just don't understand that bit. So if something in B starts with SGA or SLA you want to delete the rows that start with the same code in col A? So in your example rows 28 and 29 would be deleted? Can't you just check if the first x characters of column A are the same?

Comment: Is something in B starts with SGA or SLA i want to delete all the rows in A after cell that contain SGA or SLA number and dot. Example: SGAXXXXXX have a corrispective number in A column = 1. All sub code of SGAXXXXX are: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 and i want to delete them.

Comment: And yeah, 28 and 29 whould be deleted. Yes, i can check if the first X character match and then delete, but how can i do this of all the values?

Comment: Do the rows to be deleted always immediately follow the SLA rows? You could loop through all rows, once you find an SLA, nest a do loop which deletes rows while col A has the same first 6 characters eg 1.19.3

Comment: Yes, I have understand what you do, but i’m Unable to do that. Can you write me some suggestions to help my approach?

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: I’ve been a couples of search but nothing helping me

Answer (score 0):

I've search a lot and find something can help, but when macro work, it clear all cell in A and not only Q value

```
Sub Test()
Dim x1, x2 As Integer

For x2 = 1 To 200
  For x1 = 1 To 200
    If Range("Q" & Format(x1)).Value = Right(Range("A" & Format(x2)).Value, 1 & ".") Then
       Range("A" & Format(x1)).clear
    End If
  Next
Next
End Sub
```